# Identify Superset version from docker image

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I had earlier installed Superset locally from its docker image by following instructions in https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset.

Now I want to find what release of Superset was installed. I exported the contents of the docker image. But if I see the contents of the package.json in superset assets folder, it shows the following at the top:

"version": "0.0.dev"

The same appears in the Superset UI in the menu About. How can I find the release or version from the image content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. On inspecting the image, one can find an sha value. Then that sha can be searched for in the docker hub for Superset to find the exact image used. Even a pull can be constructed from there to pull it.

Comment: didnt work for me